# My Weather Indicator 404 error

Tags: my-weather-indicator

I have just got up this morning and noticed my-weather-indicator is not working. When I run it from the terminal I get:

```
<gettext.GNUTranslations instance at 0x2eebef0>
No LSB modules are available.
#####################################################
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS
Release:    12.04
Codename:   precise
Version:    x86_64
#####################################################

My-Weather-Indicator version: 0.6.1.2.precise.1
#####################################################
('/home/chrispche/.config/my-weather-indicator/my-weather-indicator.conf', True)
{"time":"2013-02-28 11:19","countryName":"United Kingdom","sunset":"2013-02-28 17:35","rawOffset":0,"dstOffset":1,"countryCode":"GB","gmtOffset":0,"lng":0.7,"sunrise":"2013-02-28 06:45","timezoneId":"Europe/London","lat":51.5333}
Searching url: http://where.yahooapis.com/geocode?q=51.5333,+0.7&gflags=R&flags=J&appid=_slN0oHV34Exg09kl5EASmbGBs5y3GJES1N.Oon0wd5Lnh6E5hGdtQmx_MdxpOxKAzftS1dB0yNI_NzTpWaKFXEm
GID HTTP Error 404: Not Found
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Response><Ip>92.232.83.84</Ip><Status>OK</Status><CountryCode>GB</CountryCode><CountryCode3>GBR</CountryCode3><CountryName>United Kingdom</CountryName><RegionCode>M5</RegionCode><RegionName>Southend-on-Sea</RegionName><City>Southend-on-sea</City><ZipPostalCode>SS2</ZipPostalCode><Latitude>51.5333</Latitude><Longitude>0.7000</Longitude><AreaCode>0</AreaCode><TimeZone>Europe/London</TimeZone></Response>

Yahoo Weather Service, not found woeid
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/extras.ubuntu.com/my-weather-indicator/bin/my-weather-indicator", line 46, in <module>
    mwi=MWI()
  File "/opt/extras.ubuntu.com/my-weather-indicator/share/my-weather-indicator/myweatherindicator.py", line 136, in __init__
    self.load_preferences()
  File "/opt/extras.ubuntu.com/my-weather-indicator/share/my-weather-indicator/myweatherindicator.py", line 363, in load_preferences
    self.work()
  File "/opt/extras.ubuntu.com/my-weather-indicator/share/my-weather-indicator/myweatherindicator.py", line 196, in work
    self.set_menu()
  File "/opt/extras.ubuntu.com/my-weather-indicator/share/my-weather-indicator/myweatherindicator.py", line 465, in set_menu
    temporal_current_conditions = weather['current_conditions']
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Does anyone have any ideas why switching my computer off last night with everything working, I should suddenly get this when I turn it on this morning again.

Comment: I'v made the same mistake changed to yahoo. But i don't have the config file what you are talking about. (sry for bad language) Here is a screenshot: http://kepfeltoltes.hu/view/130504/Screenshot_from_2013-05-04_23_51_03_www.kepfeltoltes.hu_.png

Answer (score 3):

The [where.yahooapis.com/geocode](http://where.yahooapis.com/geocode) seems to be down. I'm seeing same thing. Script calling this URL has been working fine for about 10 months. Stopped working today.

Perhaps Yahoo stopped offering this service or you (and I) are on the 2000 max. request per day limit. But then again, you wouldn't expect to get a 404.

More info [here](http://developer.yahoo.com/forum/PlaceFinder-Product-Announcements/http-where-yahooapis-com-geocode-appid-flags-P-not-returning-serialized-PHP-but/1349181261898-870cf85e-dc2f-4291-92c5-41754397504d)

Answer (score 1):

Something seems to be wrong in your geocode fetching: `GID HTTP Error 404: Not Found`. I do think this should normally be captured by an error msg.

There is a highly similar bugreport here: https://answers.launchpad.net/my-weather-indicator/+question/219983

The answer that worked there was:

> You provide a wrong latitude and a wrong longitude.The program can not found your location ,city,coutry etc. All the information is blanck .So the MWI won't display. Maybe you have a wrong config file.Try to delete the ~/.config/my-weather-indicator/my-weather-indicator.conf,after that to restart your program.

Try to delete the `~/.config/my-weather-indicator/my-weather-indicator.conf` and maybe reboot.

Not sure whether this qualifies as a bug.

Answer (score 1):

Same problem. Yahoo seems to have removed the GeoCode service. Here's the "official" response. I'd recommend switching to either Google (2500 daily request limit) or MapQuest (backed by OpenStreetMaps and has no request limit). Personally going to look into MapQuest / OpenStreetMap as I need another backup for when Google kicks me off.

http://developer.yahoo.com/forum/General-Discussion-at-YDN/Yahoo-GeoCode-404-Not-Found/1362061375511-7faa66ba-191d-4593-ba63-0bb8f5d43c06#forum-topic-reply-form

Answer (score 1):

delete ~/.config/my-weather-indicator/my-weather-indicator.conf then run it again.  Choose something other than Yahoo for the weather service.  World Weather Online is going to be changing their API in August so it will probably give you issues then.  Wunderground is pretty good for NYC.  Not sure how it is in other parts of the world.  You have to register for either of those two, but it's pretty easy.  Here's a link explaining how to do it http://www.webupd8.org/2013/02/how-to-use-your-own-weather-services.html.  It's been working fine for me since I did that.

Answer (score 0):

it seems that the /geocode api is gone, like this I had several apps and websites fail today (from 10:20 gmt).

any requests to /geocode fail with a 404 regardless of the params passed so this is not an error in your app.

My solution was to switch over to googles api for geolocation but that may not be an option for you.