# How can I uninstall everything I've been installing for last two days?

Tags: software-installation

I tried to install weather gadgets for days, non of them worked. The thing is that I can download and install but nothing is working. Did I did that and why?

To make things worse, than I installed this thing called `My weather indicator` that is a look-a-like to an HTC gadget, As a matter of fact, I can't uninstall it at all. It is not working, I can't open the gadget, it doesn't show on mu screen, and when I go on Dash to check it out, it shows that it exists, I see a sun and a cloud which is it icon, but it can not be opened or uninstall. There is no uninstall button and the launch button is not working.

I'm new Ubuntu user, I try to learn,and I usually make things work, but for two days it (Ubuntu) is slow, not opening apps at usual pace, and then this thing with not being able to have a weather gadget or being able to uninstall the one I mentioned. Is there a way for me to set things the way they were two days ago?

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Sorry for grammar in this, Im not that good when typing :)

Comment: look at this post: http://askubuntu.com/questions/262304/my-weather-indicator-404-error

Comment: konrad, thanks, but this did not help cause I can not go to that app and change the settings, like I wrote above...and those setting shouldn’t be interfering with me uninstalling it anyway....

Comment: try this: rm ~/.config/my-weather-indicator/my-weather-indicator.conf as described here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/my-weather-indicator/+bug/1163457

Comment: See installed package: dpkg -l | grep my-weather-indicator to remove do: sudo apt-get remove my-weather-indicator

Comment: konrad, you are the best, that helped, it is uninstall :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To remove the package:

- Open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>).
- Run the following command:

  ```
  sudo apt-get purge my-weather-indicator
  ```

  You'd need to enter your password.
- If you installed it via a ppa and you want to remove the ppa too, then you can do it by:

  ```
  sudo apt-add-repository --remove <ppa_name>
  ```
- Done!

Answer (score 0):

The history of all the packaged that had been installed on your system are contained in this file:

```
 /var/log/apt/history.log
```